# Font caching for a web page

Tags: css

In CSS, you can specify an external font like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Custom Font";
    src: url(http://www.example.org/mycustomfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: "My Custom Font", Verdana, Tahoma;
}
</style>
<p class="customfont">Hello world!</p>
```

If the user loses Internet connection after the font has been downloaded, will it still get used by the web page from a cached version? Even if it does, will the cache at some point delete it after an expiry date?

Comment: But if the cached version expires, they can still see the page but it will probably revert to using a system font.

Comment: Why wouldn't they. Browsers are designed to handle missing stuff they don't understand like custom html elements or even ignore stuff like missing files. Just because a custom font is missing is no reason to not show the page.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that that isn't true. Many components do have an expiry date and you can see this using tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather generic "solution". There is a production service, operating since years, open to the public (though check their terms for commercial use, I don't know if it fits). It is a US federally funded research project in a content distribution network.

It is called Coral and works by appending .nyud.net to any URL, for example

http://www.example.com/static/MyFont.ttf
becomes

http://www.example.com.nyud.net/static/MyFont.ttf.
There is nothing else to do. On the first request, the Coral servers fetch and cache the file (expect some delay), and then they serve it without checking again (they only check infrequently for new versions).

It is using an advanced DNS extension, DNAME records, so it might not work with very old operating systems or DNS resolvers, though anything reasonably recent is known to work. This way, requests are routed to a geographically close server.